# How to minify webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, performance, webpack, integration

I created an app based on Webpack.
Now I want to deploy the application. That means I want to create a bundle.js for production.

What is the best way to do this?
I have already tried this by setting the parameters --optimize-minimize and -p.
Still the bundle.js has almost 2M which makes the site very slow to load.

Also I would like to get rid of the bundle.js and replace it by some amd modules.

My node dependencies are:

  `"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "5.0.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^1.0.10",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "^0.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "2.10.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "4.3.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose": "^0.1.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "less-loader": "2.2.3",
    "node-sass": "3.7.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-router": "^2.1.1",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "jquery": "^2.2.2",
    "less": "^2.6.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "^0.0.4",
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.3.2"
  }`

Comment: try this https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

Comment: this is exactly what I have done. But somehow the bundle.js is getting very large.

Comment: Use a minifier and enable gzip on your server.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to minimize the size of the outcoming bundle-file, you need to add some plugins. Those two plugins reduce the size a lot.

- https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
- https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin

Also, be sure to disable source maps which add some extra size to the bundle.

You could also add these lines to your plugins configuration:

```
...
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
}),
...
```

This tells webpack that you are in production mode: This information may afterwards be used by frameworks/libraries to act differently (e.g. disable logging).

Comment: You meant `'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')`, right   ? `development` will do almost exactly nothing in this case 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `bundle.js` is consist of

If you have not yet tried then you can try these followings

1. Separate  the library and plugin files.This is called [**bundle splitting**](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/splitting-bundles/)

For example you can entry:

```
{
    app: PATHS.app,
    vendor: ['jquery','angular']
   }
```

2. You can also take a look at [**Setting environment variable**](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/setting-environment-variables/)

Comment: Thanks, this was not exactly what I was looking for, but it is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack plugins:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    })
]
```

Comment: I still get a bundle of 1.7MB.

Comment: May it be that I have to remove some dependencies?

Comment: what size it is without compressing?

Answer (score 0):

The bundle.js became so large because webpack included all the images in it.
To prevent webpack from doing this you have to change the loader to this:

`{
      test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=25000',
      include: PATHS.images
    }`

For more information read this:
http://survivejs.com/webpack/loading-assets/loading-images/